# How to display images using codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

am trying to display the images of my products in a shopping cart and this is the code am using to do that...

```
             <img src=" <?php echo 'image/'. $product['picture']?>" /><br />
```

but the images do not show. I have stored the images in a folder called image outside applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use base_url to get full path without index.php.

Hope you images folder exist in project root folder.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('image/'. $product['picture']);?>" />
```

Comment: @JoanneJuniWausi accept the answer if it is useful.